# $\liminf_r\sup\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{r}$ is upper gradient if $u$ is Lipschitz

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

> **Definition.**
>   Let $X$ be a metric space.
>   A Borel measurable function $\rho:X\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is an *upper gradient* for $u:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$, if for all $x,y\in X,x\neq y$ 
>   $$|u(x)-u(y)|\leq\int_\gamma\rho$$
>   for all rectifiable curves $\gamma$ connecting $x$ and $y$.

I want to show that, if $u$ is Lipschitz, then
$$\rho(x):=\liminf_{r\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in B(x,r)}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{r}$$
is an upper gradient for $u$.

This is an exercise from Juha Heinonen's book, Analysis on metric spaces.

A hint was to first consider the case that $X=I$ is an interval and using a suitable fine cover.

$\rho$ is well defined, since the limit is bounded by the Lipschitz constant of $u$.

Assume wlog that $x<y$.
By parametrizing $\gamma$ by arc length, we only need to consider the path
$$\gamma:[0,r],\quad\gamma(t)=x+t,$$
where $r=|x-y|$.
Then
\begin{align*}
\int_\gamma\rho
&=\int_0^r\rho(x+t)dt \\
&=\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}2^{-k}\sum_{j=0}^{2^k-1}
\sup_{t\in(rj2^{-k},r(j+1)2^{-k})}\rho(x+t) \\
&\geq\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{2^k-1}
|u(x+rj2^{-k})-u(x+r(j+1)2^{-k})| \\
&\geq\liminf_{k\rightarrow\infty}
\left|\sum_{j=0}^{2^k-1}u(x+rj2^{-k})-u(x+r(j+1)2^{-k})\right| \\
&=|u(x)-u(y)|,
\end{align*}
since the above is a telescoping sum.
Thus $\rho$ is an upper gradient for $u$.

If $X$ is an arbitrary metric space, then we can do the same thing.
Parametrize $\gamma$ by arc length, so that $|\gamma'|=1$.
Then
$$\int_\gamma\rho
=\int_I \rho\circ\gamma(t)dt,
$$
and now we can use the above calculation.
Is this sufficient?